# Problema ao retornar uma lista de vetor

Tags: java

Eu estou com fazendo um Projeto em Java e estou tendo dificuldades em mexer com vetores.
No projeto eu tenho os seguintes métodos para criar:

> 1 - Crie um método que recebe como parâmetro o nome de curso e retorne todos os alunos matriculados neste curso e também, mostre todos os professores que
>   lecionam neste curso.
>    **2 - Crie um método que recebe como parâmetro uma disciplina e retorne a quantidade de alunos cadastrados nela.**
>    3 - Crie um método que recebe como parâmetro um nome de aluno e retorne todas informações sobre ele.
>    4 - Crie um método que retorne quantos alunos do sexo feminino existem na
>   universidade.

Consegui elaborar quase todos, menos o item 2. Estou tentando retornar informações deste método e não está sendo possível.

Classe Aluno

```
package universidade;

public class Aluno {
    private String nome, curso;
    private int idade, semestre;
    private char sexo;
    private String disciplinas[];
    private float notas[];

    public Aluno() {
    }

    public Aluno(String nome, String curso, int idade, int semestre, char sexo, String[] disciplinas, float[] notas) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.curso = curso;
        this.idade = idade;
        this.semestre = semestre;
        this.sexo = sexo;
        this.disciplinas = disciplinas;
        this.notas = notas;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Nome: "+nome+
                " - Curso: "+curso+
                " - Idade: "+idade+
                " - Semestre "+semestre+
                " - Sexo"+sexo
                ;
    }



    /**
     * @return the nome
     */
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    /**
     * @param nome the nome to set
     */
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    /**
     * @return the curso
     */
    public String getCurso() {
        return curso;
    }

    /**
     * @param curso the curso to set
     */
    public void setCurso(String curso) {
        this.curso = curso;
    }

    /**
     * @return the idade
     */
    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    /**
     * @param idade the idade to set
     */
    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }

    /**
     * @return the semestre
     */
    public int getSemestre() {
        return semestre;
    }

    /**
     * @param semestre the semestre to set
     */
    public void setSemestre(int semestre) {
        this.semestre = semestre;
    }

    /**
     * @return the sexo
     */
    public char getSexo() {
        return sexo;
    }

    /**
     * @param sexo the sexo to set
     */
    public void setSexo(char sexo) {
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }

    /**
     * @return the disciplinas
     */
    public String[] getDisciplinas() {
        return disciplinas;
    }

    /**
     * @param disciplinas the disciplinas to set
     */
    public void setDisciplinas(String[] disciplinas) {
        this.disciplinas = disciplinas;
    }

    /**
     * @return the notas
     */
    public float[] getNotas() {
        return notas;
    }

    /**
     * @param notas the notas to set
     */
    public void setNotas(float[] notas) {
        this.notas = notas;
    }


}
```

Classe Universidade

```
package universidade;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Universidade {

    private Aluno alunos[];
    private Professor professores[];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Universidade();
    }

    public Universidade() {

        dadosDeAlunos_Professores();
        String nomecurso = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite o nome do Curso", "Dados", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        System.out.println(alunosMatriculados(nomecurso));

        // String nomedisciplina = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite o nome do Curso", "Dados", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        //System.out.println(alunosDisciplina(nomedisciplina+"test"));
        alunosDoSexoFeminino();

        String nomealuno = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite o nome do aluno para pesquisar - lo ", "Dados", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        System.out.println(pesquisarAlunos(nomealuno));

        String nomedisciplina = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite o nome da disciplina", "Dados", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        System.out.println(alunosDisciplina(nomedisciplina));

    }

    public void dadosDeAlunos_Professores() {

        alunos = new Aluno[3];
        professores = new Professor[3];

        //dados de vários alunos:
        String disc0[] = {"poo", "tda", "física"};
        float not0[] = {5.0f, 3.0f, 2.0f};
        alunos[0] = new Aluno("Ana", "ADS", 22, 2, 'F', disc0, not0);

        String disc1[] = {"matemática", "tda", "inteligência artificial"};
        float not1[] = {1.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f};
        alunos[1] = new Aluno("Joao", "ADS", 22, 2, 'M', disc1, not1);

        String disc2[] = {"desenho", "projeto 1", "pontes"};
        float not2[] = {5.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f};
        alunos[2] = new Aluno("Maria", "ADS", 20, 2, 'F', disc2, not2);

        //System.out.println(disc0+" "+not0);
    }

    public String alunosMatriculados(String nomecurso) {
        String saida = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < alunos.length; i++) {
            if (alunos[i].getCurso().equalsIgnoreCase(nomecurso)) {
                saida += "" + alunos[i].getNome() + ", ";
            }
        }
        return saida;
    }

    public String alunosDisciplina(String nomedisciplina) {

        String saida = "";
        int cont = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < alunos.length; i++) {
            if (alunos[i].getDisciplinas().equals(nomedisciplina)) {
                saida += ""+cont++;
            }
        }
        return saida;
    }

    public void alunosDoSexoFeminino() {
        int cont = 0;
        //char genero ='f';
        for (int i = 0; i < alunos.length; i++) {
            //equalsIgnoreCase
            if (alunos[i].getSexo() == 'F' || alunos[i].getSexo() == 'f') {
                cont++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Na universidade possui " + cont + " alunas do Sexo Feminino");

    }

    public String pesquisarAlunos(String nomealuno) {
        String saida = "";
        System.out.println("Aluno pesquisado: " + nomealuno);
        for (int i = 0; i < alunos.length; i++) {
            if (alunos[i].getNome().equalsIgnoreCase(nomealuno)) {
                saida += alunos[i].toString();
            }
        }
        return saida;
    }
}
```

Classe professor

```
package universidade;

public class Professor {
    private String nome;
    private int idade;
    private char sexo;
    private double salario;
    private String disciplinas[];

    public Professor() {
    }

    public Professor(String nome, int idade, char sexo, double salario, String[] disciplinas) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.idade = idade;
        this.sexo = sexo;
        this.salario = salario;
        this.disciplinas = disciplinas;
    }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return ""+nome+
                   " "+idade+
                   " "+sexo+
                   " "+salario+
                   " "+disciplinas; //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }



        /**
         * @return the nome
         */
        public String getNome() {
            return nome;
        }

        /**
         * @param nome the nome to set
         */
        public void setNome(String nome) {
            this.nome = nome;
        }

        /**
         * @return the idade
         */
        public int getIdade() {
            return idade;
        }

        /**
         * @param idade the idade to set
         */
        public void setIdade(int idade) {
            this.idade = idade;
        }

        /**
         * @return the sexo
         */
        public char getSexo() {
            return sexo;
        }

        /**
         * @param sexo the sexo to set
         */
        public void setSexo(char sexo) {
            this.sexo = sexo;
        }

        /**
         * @return the salario
         */
        public double getSalario() {
            return salario;
        }

        /**
         * @param salario the salario to set
         */
        public void setSalario(double salario) {
            this.salario = salario;
        }

        /**
         * @return the disciplinas
         */
        public String[] getDisciplinas() {
            return disciplinas;
        }

        /**
         * @param disciplinas the disciplinas to set
         */
        public void setDisciplinas(String[] disciplinas) {
            this.disciplinas = disciplinas;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Você já implementou o numero 2, o método `alunosDisciplina` já faz isso. Ao inves de concatenar, basta incrementar 1 cada vez que localizar aluno.

Comment: Sim, eu já tinha feito isso anteriormente. Mas mesmo assim, ao tentar imprimir essa informação na tela utilizando o System.out.println, ele não me mostra nada.

Comment: Gabriel, sua classe Aluno não tem mecanismos que localizem apenas uma disciplina, você está retornando um array das disciplinas e verificando se ele é igual ao nome, dessa forma nunca irá funcionar. Recomendo que torne Disciplina abstrato também, ao inves de usar array de string, ou crie alguma forma de pesquisar disciplinas no array que voce criou na classe Aluno

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seu erro pode ter relação com o tipo de método, já que deve ser do tipo `INT` que é o número de disciplinas que será retornada.

```
public int alunosMatriculados(String nomecurso) {
    int numAlunos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < alunos.length; i++) {
        if (alunos[i].getCurso().equalsIgnoreCase(nomecurso)) {
            numAlunos++;
        }
    }
    return numAlunos;
}
```